# Mac crashes every time I try to run boot2docker

Tags: macos, crash

I recently got a new MacBook Pro running OS X 10.10.2, and I installed boot2docker 1.5.0 on it. Aside from Chrome, this is the first program I installed on my new machine. However, when I try to run it, the terminal window opens up for a few seconds, saying boot2docker is up, and then my computer restarts automatically.

I tried to uninstall 1.5.0 and install 1.4.1 (as that is what I was using on my last machine), but I encountered the same problem.

The last thing I see before my laptop restarts is this:

[image]

The error report my computer shows after the restart is this:

[image]

Has anyone every had this problem before, or know how I can address it?

EDIT: I downloaded the installer from boot2docker's github repo: github.com/boot2docker/osx-installer/releases

Comment: I forgot to mention, I downloaded the installer from boot2docker's github repo: https://github.com/boot2docker/osx-installer/releases

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! When uploading images, please use the official image uploader for longevity of the images. If you wish to add additional information to your question, use the edit button rather than adding an ephemeral comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a problem with OS X Security Update 2015-003 and boot2docker/virtualbox as discussed here:

https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/issues/800

The fix is to install the latest VirtualBox.